# Chaining to clean up CompareTo

Tags: c#

Every time I need to write a `CompareTo` method in C#, I hate the fact that I can't chain the tests and results like you would in JavaScript:

```
function int compareTo(a, b) {
    return a.Value1 - b.Value1 || a.Value2 - b.Value2 || a.Value3 - b.Value3;
}
```

Instead in C# this looks like:

```
int CompareTo(object obj)
{
    var other = obj as MyClass;
    if (other == null)
        return 0;
    int result = Value1 - other.Value1;
    if (result != 0)
        return result;
    result = Value2 - other.Value2;
    if (result != 0)
        return result;
    return Value3 - other.Value3;
}
```

Is there a way to write the above 'cleaner'? It doesn't have to be a one-liner like in JavaScript, but should be more readable and less error-prone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a generic extension method `NullableCompareTo` we can now make use of the [`?? operator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) to refactor the `CompareTo` method to:

```
int CompareTo(object obj)
{
    var other = obj as MyClass;
    if (other == null)
        return 0;
    return Value1.NullableCompareTo(other.Value1)
        ?? Value2.NullableCompareTo(other.Value2)
        ?? Value3.CompareTo(other.Value3);
}
```

**Extension method**

```
public static class ComparableExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Same as CompareTo but returns null instead of 0 if both items are equal.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">IComparable type.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="this">This instance.</param>
    /// <param name="other">The other instance.</param>
    /// <returns>Lexical relation between this and the other instance or null if both are equal.</returns>
    public static int? NullableCompareTo<T>(this T @this, T other) where T : IComparable
    {
        var result = @this.CompareTo(other);
        return result != 0 ? result : (int?)null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I personally hate names like `_` and it's not really *one liner*. Also, original one is much more *cleaner* version (more obvious what is going on). Is this solution *faster* or how is it better?

Comment: @Sinatr it is called `test` in my code, but changed it to `_` for readability in the answer. If you can come up with a cleaner version, please share

Comment: @Xaruth no, that's called sharing. And btw, I hope my answer is not the best answer and someone will come up with a more language integrated solution.

Comment: That's the point. Code in your question would be my answer. It's already good. I would appreciate sharing of something what is good.  Using lambda and `??` operator is not really impressive to replace multiple `if` and null-checks if they don't have benefits. I don't see them. It should be slower, less obvious. So what makes this solution better?

Comment: Code in my question is obviously less readable and more error-prone. It shows only 3 cases, but sometimes you have 10+ cases where things can easily go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an extension method to mimic `??`.

```
public static class Extensions {
    public static T Coalesce<T>( this T self, T valueIfDefault ) {
        return self.Equals( default(T) ) ? valueIfDefault : self;
    }
}
```

For example, `0.Coalesce(1).Coalesce(2)`, `0.Coalesce(0).Coalesce(1)`, and `1.Coalesce(2).Coalesce(3)` would each be 1.

You could use a shorter name depending on your personal preferences regarding clarity versus concision.

Here's the comparison method from the question rewritten in this style:

```
int CompareTo(object obj) {
    var other = obj as MyClass;
    if( other == null )
        return 0;
    return (Value1 - other.Value1).Coalesce(Value2 - other.Value2)
                                  .Coalesce(Value3 - other.Value3);
}
```

If the individual comparisons are expensive, you could also add:

```
public static T Coalesce<T>( this T self, Func<T> valueIfDefault ) {
    return self.Equals( default(T) ) ? valueIfDefault() : self;
}
```

This would be called like `(Value1 - other.Value1).Coalesce(() => CompareExpensively(Value2, other.Value2)).Coalesce(Value3 - other.Value3)`.

Comment: Problem with this solution is that you're evaluating each value beforehand. That's why I'm using a lambda function, next value will only be evaluated if previous equals 0.

Comment: They are `int` subtractions, so I don't consider that a significant  downside. Your answer has extra branches; there are 6 vs 2 in mine, i.e. 2n vs n-1, in the post-null-test code. Without benchmarking, those extra branches seem at least as likely to adversely impact performance. The verbose method in the question is likely faster than both, anyway.

Also, did you downvote my answer over that?

Comment: I expanded my answer to cover that case.

Comment: They are `int` subtraction because I simplified the question, in my code their are some `string.Compare()` calls to, so that changes the case.